# IBM WAS apache httpcore and httpclient

Tags: java, apache, websphere

I have IBM WAS 8.5.5.0 and I have to use java project with apache httpcore and httpclietn jar with 4.4.1 version. It works. But when I try to deploy on my app server I face some problems.

**java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE**

I've already get that this error occures when there are two version of one jar file. So I created a shared library with isolated class loader and parent_last. Reloaded and redeployed my app. But I still have this error.

Am I missing something?

1) Should this 4.4.1 jars be added in build path in my project?

2) When I create my shared library does it matter where should I put my jar files (fro class path)?

3) Should I put jars in libs/ext folder? (I suppose not)

4) May version of WAS 8.5.5.0 be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 8.5.5.9 and later you should be able to bundle them in your application without any additional configuration (such as adding them to an isolated shared library).

Prior to 8.5.5.9, simply adding them as a shared library (location doesn't matter) and associating them with your application should have been sufficient. See APAR PI50993.

From a practical perspective, there's little sense in worrying about how it works prior to 8.5.5.9 though, since 8.5.5.8 is nearly 18 months old and in 4 months won't be eligible for new fixes.